# Many BlocListener Registered with Navigation.pushName() on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a problem with register of **BlocListener** with [Flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

I have 3 Widget, let's say **Widget1**, **Widget2** and **Widget3**.
In Widget1 that is a initialRoute I have registered my **BlocListener** for SnackBar:

```
class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  BlocListener<SnackbarBloc, SnackbarState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is SnackbarSuccess) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('${state.message}'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ));
        }
        if (state is SnackbarError) {
          Scaffold.of(context)..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('${state.message}'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ));
        }
      },
      child: Container();
    )
  }
}
```

So when I create my Widget1 I register my SnackBarListener.
In my app I have a NavigationBloc and Listener for handle the navigation like:

```
BlocListener<NavigationBloc, NavigationState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is Widget1) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/widget1');
    }
    if (state is Widget2) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/widget2');
    }
    if (state is Widget3) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/widget3');
    }

  },
)
```

Once time I change my page to Widget2, and then I return in Widget1 with NavigationBloc and so with Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/widget1');
the listener for snackBar in Widget1 is re-registered so if I try to open my snackbar the function:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  content: Text('${state.message}'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
));
```

For more clarity I have create a gist that is an example of my problem

https://gist.github.com/loreberti89/a916d03ed20ea10484fae3cb001964cf

Is called twice, and then 3 times and so on.

How Should I handle these cases?

Comment: you are keep pushing new screens on top of each other that’s why this is happening. To avoid this you can use Navigation.of(context).pop(); to go to back in widget1 from widget2.

Comment: thankyou, yes, i know that is a problem with stack.
And yes, pop could be util, but if I have 3 page where I can navigate in beetween page. I edited my gist for test the app.
Widget1 -> Widget2 -> Widget3 -> Widget1 and in this moment the listener is register twice and the listener of Widget2 is still alive. and If i return from Widget1 to Widget2 the listener of Widget2 is re-registered

Comment: i think that it is obvious behaviour that listener is re-register when you move from widget1 to widget2 in the end because you are registering listener in widget2. I also think that we can not avoid this with listener because we don't have listenerprovider as blocprovider.  You can try with blocprovider by registering them in InitialRedirect widget.